# dynamic pageblockbuttons not showing on bottom location

Tags: visualforce-component, dynamic, dynamic-vf-component, pageblock

i'm trying to show pageblock button in bottom side but its not showing on bottom only showing in top location
how to set bottom

```
  Component.Apex.pageBlockButtons pbButtons = new Component.Apex.pageBlockButtons();        
    pbButtons.location = 'top'; //<b>Bottom</b> this is not supprting
    pbButtons.id = 'myPBButtons';

    Component.Apex.outputPanel opPanel = new Component.Apex.outputPanel();
    opPanel.id = 'myButtons';

    //the Previous button will alway be displayed
    Component.Apex.commandButton b1 = new Component.Apex.commandButton();
    b1.expressions.action = '{!Previous}';
    b1.title = 'Previous';
    b1.value = 'Previous';
    b1.expressions.disabled = '{!disablePrevious}';        
    b1.reRender = theSet;
```

Comment: As per documentation, "bottom" is supported. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockButtons.htm

Comment: not working you can also test use this link for testing in your org 
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000098QYIAY

Comment: "bottom" is supported. Can you please post some more code snippet. Check this link https://gist.github.com/tyoshikawa1106/5376613